# Checking user input in C#

Tags: c#, math

I just wrote my first C# console application, I am still a beginner. Anyway, I tried the code below and it seems to work, its for solving quadratic equations. I'd like to add code for a situation whereby a user inputs a string instead of an integer and give an error message any ideas as to how to implement this?

```
namespace Quadratic_equation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("welcome to seyi's quadratic calculator!!!");
            Console.Write("a:");
            double a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.Write("b:");
            double b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("c:");
            double c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) < 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("There are no real roots!");
            }
            else {
                double x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c)) /2*a;
                double x2 = (-b + Math.Sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c)) /2*a;
                Console.WriteLine("x:{0}",x1);
                Console.WriteLine("y:{0}",x2);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use TryParse and if it returns false show error and don't continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Int32.TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check your string is a valid integer or not. This method returns a `boolean` value for your conversation is succeed or not.

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded.

And I don't understand why you want to keep as `double` the return value of [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. These factors (a, b, c) should be integer, not double.

```
int a;
string s = Console.ReadLine();
if(Int32.TryParse(s, out a))
{
   // Your input string is a valid integer.
}
else
{
  // Your input string is not a valid integer.
}
```

This `Int32.TryParse(string, out int)` overload uses [`NumberStyle.Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as default. That means your string can have **one of** these;

- Trailing white spaces
- Leading white spaces
- Leading sign character

Comment: `strings` is an invalid variable type. Was that a typo?

Comment: @jsve Yeah, that was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

```
   int number;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
  if (result)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
  }
  else
  {
     if (value == null) value = ""; 
     Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", value);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `try-catch` block in a `do-while` loop:

```
bool goToNextNum = false;
do
{
    try
    {
        double a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        goToNextNum = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number");
    }
} while (goToNextNum == false);
```

This will loop until `a` is a valid number.